# A section of object duplicated in pose mode. [Answers provided in similar questions did not help]

Tags: armature, pose-mode, duplicate

[image: Object gets duplicated in pose mode]

I am creating a figure with armatures and IK constraints. When I go into pose mode, the right lower leg gets duplicated; the other is fine. I checked for duplicate objects by 'merging vertices by distance' that returned 0 objects found. Next, I followed the instruction on similar questions by re-assigning the parenting of the body to the armature, but that didn't help either. Next, I selected view by bounds, as explained in another answer, which also did not solve the problem—attaching the .blend file through Blend-Exchange.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You model has huge problems with face orientation:

[image]

That's why it cannot work.

you can check face orientation in viewport overlays -> face orientation.

Red means: wrong, blue means: ok

[image]

So select your object, edit mode -> Shift N (recalculate normals)

Reassign body to armature with automatic weights, then it works:

[image]